# Object become a null after I put it in coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, coroutine

I want to store my state in repository and do in acynchronously.
Here I preparing my state and putting it in coroutine.

```
fun saveState(state: MapState) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            mapRepository.saveState(state, mapRepository.defaultStateId)
        }
    }
}
```

But already in next function "saveState" I found, that my object "mOutline" in "MapState" became null.
[Object before putting in coroutine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsLaV.png)
[Object after putting in coroutine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAk85.png)
And after all I get NullPointerExeption when trying to handle object.
I tryed this code without coroutine and it worked well.
Maybe I do something wrong with coroutine?
There is my project on GitHub https://github.com/Panicia/Wegitantion_index_counter/tree/master/app/src/main/java/viewModels/mapViewModel

Comment: I don't know why the object should become null just by calling `saveState` but you should read up on coroutines. None of the functions you call are `suspend` functions, especially not the Dao ones so the db operations will run synchronously (alas on a background thread). If you use the suspend functions, you don't even need to explicitly use `Dispatchers.IO`.

Comment: Looking closely at your screenshots, you are comparing two different ArrayList instances, and they have different MyPolygon instances in them. This would have nothing to do with your code posted above. Whatever you're doing to produce unexpected results is happening elsewhere.